# map a big file and scan through data

Tags: c, linux

Trying to search a pattern in a big file using mmap.  The file is huge (way more than the physical memory). My worry is that if I used the file size as the second parameter for mmap(), there won't be enough physical memory to satisfy the system call.  So I used 0x1000 as the length in the hope that OS will automatically map the right part of file as my pointer moves. But the following code snippet gave segmentation fault.

Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

long fileSize(char *fname) {
    struct stat stat_buf;
    int rc = stat(fname, &stat_buf);
    return rc == 0 ? stat_buf.st_size : -1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long size = fileSize(argv[1]);
    printf("size=%ld\n", size);
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    printf("fd=%d\n", fd);
    char *p = mmap(0, 0x1000, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror ("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    long i;
    int pktLen;
    int *pInt;
    for (i=0; i < size; i+=4) {
        pInt = (int*)(p+i);
        if (pInt[i] == 0x12345678) {
            printf("found it at %ld\n", i); break;
        }
    }
    if (i == size) {
        printf("didn't find it\n");
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**
Turned out I had a silly bug

The line 
`if (pInt[i] == 0x12345678)`  should have been `if (pInt[0] == 0x12345678)`

Comment: "My worry is that if I used the file size as the second parameter for mmap(), there won't be enough physical memory". Mapping a file does not immediately reserve that amount of physical memory. So your concern is unfounded. Virtual mem on the other hand could be a problem. "in the hope that OS will automatically map the right part of file as my pointer moves". On what are you basing that hope - why not read the man page and find out what it actually does?

Comment: @kaylum, the man page only mentions `The length argument specifies the length of the mapping`, it doesn't address my concern that I may run out of memory (RES or VM) while doing this operation. I really doesn't need lots of memory since I just need to read a small segment at a time.

Comment: If the file is big, use regular I/O instead of memory mapping.  You won't run out of space.  It's especially easy where you don't have to worry about the pattern matching between successive blocks, which looks to be the case here as long as the block size is a multiple of 4.  If you're only scanning a file once, memory mapping isn't all that useful.  If you're scanning many times, it makes more sense — if the file fits in memory.  Consider whether the `memmem()` function provides any help.

Comment: @packetie But where does it say `mmap` will magically change the mapping for you as you read? You need to slide that window yourself if you want to do it that way.

Comment: When mapping a file with `mmap` it is supposed (implementation depends) to create a virtual memory map entry for the CPU's memory address translator. This entry will have a flag signifying that the memory address is actually a device related IO... As far as I know, no physical memory should be assigned to hold the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SIGSEGV` is because you're accessing beyond `0x1000` bytes (in the `for` loop). You have to `mmap()` the complete `size` bytes of the `fd`.

The concept of **demand paging** in **virtual memory subsystem** helps exact same scenarios like yours - applications/application data bigger than the physical memory size. After the `mmap()`, as and when you access the (virtual) address, if there is no physical page mapped to it (**page fault**), kernel will find out a physical page that can be used (**page replacement**).

```
fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

ptr = mmap(NULL, file_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

/* Consume the entire file's data as needed */

munmap(ptr, file_size);
```

Alternately you can put a loop around the `mmap()/munmap()` to scan the file in `PAGE_SIZE` or in multiples of `PAGE_SIZE`. The last arg of `mmap() - offset` will come handy for that.

From man-page :

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
int munmap(void *addr, size_t length);
```

Pseudo-code :

```
fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

last_block_size = file_size % PAGE_SIZE;
num_pages = file_size / PAGE_SIZE + (last_block_size ? 1 : 0)

for (int i = 0; i < num_pages; i++) {
    block_size = last_block_size && (i == num_pages - 1) ? last_block_size : PAGE_SIZE;

    ptr = mmap(NULL, block_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, i * PAGE_SIZE);

    /* Consume the file's data range (ptr, ptr+block_size-1) as needed */

    munmap(ptr, block_size);
}
```

Please use **`MAP_PRIVATE`** as the mapping might be just needed for your process alone. It just avoids few extra steps by the kernel for the **`MAP_SHARED`**.

Edit : It should have been `MAP_PRIVATE` in place of `MAP_ANON`. Changed.

Comment: Thanks @ReddyVeeru for detailed response. I tried both `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_PRIVATE` and in my both cases, my RES and VM memory useage go very high and eventually the program died.  Any ideas?

Comment: @packetie - Please double check all the variable's data types for any overflow situation.
What is the size of your data file?
Since `i+=4` is used in `for (i=0; i < size; i+=4)`, `size` has to be rounded down to nearest multiple of 4 if it's not already.

Comment: Here is my working version - http://pastebin.com/K5mxPJs4
Unfortunately, max file size that I could test was "4GB-1B (one byte less than 4GB)" on x86-64bit processor with 64bit Ubuntu. File generated with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=bigfile.txt count=4194304 bs=1024` command.

Comment: @ReddyVeeru: Memory maps are restricted in size to RAM + swap by default. (In your case, the size limit sounds like a file system limitation, though.) In any case, when using a backing file, you can use the `MAP_NORESERVE` flag to tell the kernel that this mapping is directly backed by the file, so the RAM + swap limit does not apply. You need to `#define _BSD_SOURCE` for that flag to be defined in `<sys/mman.h>`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal : Yes, the size limitation was due to `msdos` fs. Your point about RAM + SWAP size `mmap` restriction makes sense. I have not experimented the `MAP_NORESERVE` flag though.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
    struct stat  info;
    long         page;
    const char  *map;
    size_t       size, mapping;
    int          fd, result;

    page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    if (page < 1L) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid page size.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot open file: %s.\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = fstat(fd, &info);
    if (result == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot get file information: %s.\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (info.st_size <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: No data.\n", filename);
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size = info.st_size;
    if ((off_t)size != info.st_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: File is too large to map.\n", filename);
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* mapping is size rounded up to a multiple of page. */
    if (size % (size_t)page)
        mapping = size + page - (size % (size_t)page);
    else
        mapping = size;

    map = mmap(NULL, mapping, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot map file: %s.\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (close(fd)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unexpected error closing file descriptor.\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*
     * Use map[0] to map[size-1], but remember that it is not a string,
     * and that there is no trailing '\0' at map[size].
     *
     * Accessing map[size] to map[mapping-1] is not allowed, and may
     * generate a SIGBUS signal (and kill the process).
    */

    /* The mapping is automatically torn down when the process exits,
     * but you can also unmap it with */
    munmap(map, mapping);
```

The important points in the code above:

1. You'll need to start your code with e.g.

   ```
   #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
   #define _BSD_SOURCE
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <sys/mman.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   ```

   The `_BSD_SOURCE` is required for `MAP_NORESERVE` to be defined, even though it is a GNU/Linux-specific feature.
2. `mapping` (`length` in [`man 2 mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)) must be a multiple of page size (`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`).
3. `MAP_NORESERVE` flag tells the kernel that the mapping is backed by the file only, and as such, is allowed to be larger than available RAM + SWAP.
4. You can (but do not need to) close the file descriptor referring to the mapped file with no issues, because the mapping itself contains a reference in-kernel.

Years ago, on a different forum, I showed [a simple program to manipulate a terabyte of data](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/data-type-in-c-to-hold-tetrabyte-875026/#post4324888) (1 TiB = 1,099,511,627,776 bytes) using this very approach (although it uses a sparse backing file; i.e. mostly implicit zeroes, with less than 250 MB of actual data written to the backing file -- mostly to reduce the amount of disk space needed). Of course, it requires a 64-bit machine running Linux, as the virtual memory on 32-bit machines is limited to 2<sup>32</sup> = 4 GiB (Linux does not support segmented memory models).

The Linux kernel is surprisingly efficient in choosing which pages to keep in RAM, and which pages to evict. Of course, you can make that even more efficient, by telling the kernel which parts of the mapping you are unlikely to access (and therefore can be evicted), by using [`posix_madvise(address, length, advice)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_madvise.3.html) with `advice` being `POSIX_MADV_DONTNEED` or `POSIX_MADV_WILLNEED`. This has the benefit that unlike unmapping the "dontneed" parts, you can, if you need to, re-access that part of the mapping. (If the pages are already evicted, the access to the mapping will just block until the pages are re-loaded to memory. In other words, you can use `posix_madvise()` to "optimize" eviction logic, without limiting what part of the mapping can be accessed.)

In your case, if you do a linear or semi-linear search over the data using e.g. [`memmem()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html), you can use `posix_madvise(map, mapping, POSIX_MADV_SEQUENTIAL)`.

Personally, I'd run the search first without using any `posix_madvise()` calls, and then see if it makes a significant enough positive difference, using the same data set (and several runs, of course). (You can safely -- with no risk of losing any data -- clear the page cache between test runs using `sudo sh -c 'sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ; sync'`, if you wish to exclude the effects of having the large file (mostly) already cached, between timing runs.)

Comment: thanks a lot @nominal-animal for the detailed explanation.  It's amazing that you can process 1TB file this way.  I tried the sample code in the original post (with the silly bug fixed), saw that the RES memory usage jumps to 4.2GB. Using `posix_madvise(map, mapping, POSIX_MADV_SEQUENTIAL)` didn't seem to reduce the peak memory consumption.  Wonder if there is a way to limit the peek memory.  Thanks

Comment: @packetie: If you know the patterns you are looking for -- either fixed ones, or e.g. regular expressions --, you can build a finite state machine (i.e. write code that generates the finite state machine for looking for the specified patterns) to look for the patterns in parallel, in which case you only need a single pass over the data, and no memory map is needed. Another option is to only map the data partially, in e.g. 512 MiB + maximum-length-of-pattern "windows", sliding the window up by 512 MiB at a time. It all depends on your pattern-finding code.